# Tool to validate migrated data from RDBMS to mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, rdbms

I need to create a python tool to validate the completeness and accuracy of migrated data from a**RDBMS DB to MongoDB**. It should support at least **30 tables** and **1 million records** (in the source).

I am aware that consistency checkers, for example, *MD5 checksums*, can be used to validate the same, but since I am new to python, can anybody please share their views if they have done a similar activity in the past (or any hint would be appreciated).

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: if thats the case, can you please message me?